# Refresh records in LWC?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, lwc

I am using a apex method that returns Map which contain multiple object records. So how can I refresh that records after updating some of them. I am updating them but it is not showing updated value without refreshing a page. Are there any way to refresh that records?
I tried refreshApex but as I understand it works just with methods which return List.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are using wire or imperative call?

Comment: I am not using Wire. I am not sure but it can be imperative call.

Answer (score 0):

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334645/reload-data-table-records-after-an-imperative-apex-call-in-lwc
try it for reference ,Refresh apex needs to be called on wiredProperty itself, not data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32398529)